# drupal7 custom user_registration_submit

Tags: drupal-7, customization, user-registration

`function hendrenfoundation_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
     switch($form_id){
           case 'user_register_form':
               $form['#submit'][] = 'hendrenfoundation_user_register_submit';
               $form['#validate'][] = 'hendrenfoundation_user_register_validate';
               break;
        }
}`

but it doesn't work, I even find the original user module function and comment it, But the registration page works well. So what's the problem.

Comment: can you elaborate more, please?

Answer (score 0):

Clear your website cache to fix your issue.

To learn how to do that, see http://drupal.org/node/326504